# Passing variables as parameters from one function to multiple functions

Tags: javascript

In my script I've got a function `createEl()` where I declare 2 variables and call 2 other functions passing those declared variables to those 2 functions.

By clicking on one link first function is supposed to add 10px to `divp`'s height. By clicking on another link the second function should deduct 10px from `div`'s height.

It doesn't work as expected though. I believe I have to call those 2 functions from my first functions in some different manner? Now the result is that whichever link I click those 10px are always deducted. Please help.

P.S. I am seeking for an option without global variables, rather just pass the variables as parameters from one function to multiple functions.

HTML:

```
<a href="" onclick="createEl();return false;">Larger</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="" onclick="createEl();return false;">Smaller</a>

<div id='box'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function createEl() {
    var x = document.getElementById('box');
    var h = x.offsetHeight;

    large(x,h);
    small(x,h);
}

function large(x,h) {
    x.style.height = h + 10 + "px";
}

function small(x,h) {
    x.style.height = h - 10 + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Update your HTML to send an identifier parameter to the function call.

```
<a href="" onclick="createEl('large');return false;">Larger</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="" onclick="createEl('small');return false;">Smaller</a>
<div id='box'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function createEl(funcName){

        var x = document.getElementById('box');
        var h = x.offsetHeight;

        if(funcName =="large") large(x,h); //depending on the parameter call the required function
        else small(x,h);
}
```

Comment: it may also be worth mentioning that the functions `large` and `small` can be declared inside the scope of `createEl` if they are not called from any other place.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the offset as a parameter, and create a generic `changeHeight(offset)` function.

Would this match your requirements?

HTML :

```
<a href="" onclick="changeHeight(10);return false;">Larger</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="" onclick="changeHeight(-10);return false;">Smaller</a>
<div id='box'></div>
```

JavaScript :

```
changeHeight(offset) {
    var x = document.getElementById('box');
    x.style.height = (x.offsetHeight + offset) + "px";
}
```